# What is the internal schematic for a 74HC series gate (NAND gate as an example)?

Tags: logic-gates, cmos, high-speed

It's rather easy to find the schematics for a CMOS NAND gate on the net -- two series NMOS transistors as the pull-down network, two parallel PMOS transistors as the pull-up network.

What would an HCMOS (74HCxx) NAND gate schematic look like? What is done differently to make it high-speed?

Comment: https://project5474.org/index.php?title=Main_Page might interest you

Comment: Some examples https://learnabout-electronics.org/Digital/dig32.php and CMOS "transmission gates" https://learnabout-electronics.org/Digital/dig55.php

Comment: Not exact, but related: https://zeptobars.com/en/read/NXP-74AHC00

Comment: FYI, nothing is done to make them "high speed", in fact they're rather slow (worst case) as (5-6V rated) CMOS logic families go.

Comment: Tim Williams: Do you mean that they are slow compared to original 74 or 74LS, previous CMOS series, or 74C? I do understand that they are slow compared to a NAND that is shrinked down to a few nanometers.

Comment: Mat: This is really interesting. If no more direct answer comes in a few days, I'd like to accept this as "the" answer, but you'd have to turn it into an answer first.

Comment: >What would an HCMOS (74HCxx) NAND gate schematic look like?  At VLSI design?